# Author attributes and values defined using the xkeyval package

Tags: xkeyval

I try to define command key author attributes like "corresponding author address, corresponding author email, present address, auto string capture the author name"  using `xkeyval` package.

I will try to the below mentioned coding logic execute using the `xkeyval` package

```
\author[aff={1},link={http://people/u/41922},coraddress={Professor of Plant Molecular Biology},email={keith.lindsey@durham.ac.uk}]{Junli Liu}
```

But I don't know how to execute using a command key concept. Currently I am using "authblk" package and achieve my required author style. My required output is below mentioned here....

[image]

The below mentioned coding currently I am using. How to achieve this goal through the `xkeyval` package. Please advise

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \null
\vbox to \textheight{\vbox to \textheight{\vspace*{12pc}%\vfill%
\hbox to 10pc{\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{10pc}
{\@correspondence\par}%
    \vskip 6pt%
{\@presentaddress}%
\end{minipage}}}
\hspace*{11pc}
\vbox to \textheight{\vspace*{-44pc}%
\hbox to 10pc{\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{31pc}  
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\raggedright\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}\selectfont\@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
        \raggedright\@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
   \end{minipage}}}}%
  \par
  \vskip 8.5em}


\def\@correspondence{}
\def\correspondence#1{%
     \gdef\@correspondence{\textbf{\textit{*Correspondence:}}\newline%
       \raggedright  #1}}

\def\@presentaddress{}
\def\presentaddress#1{%
     \gdef\@presentaddress{\textbf{\textit{$\dagger$presentaddress:}}\newline%
       \raggedright  #1}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development}
\author[1,]{Junli Liu}
\author[2]{James Rowe}
\author[2]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}
\correspondence{Junli Liu is Professor of Plant Molecular Biology \newline e-mail: \href{mailto:keith.lindsey@durham.ac.uk}{keith.lindsey@durham.ac.uk}}
\presentaddress{James Rowe continued from this author address\newline e-mail: James@durham.ac.uk }
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: With other words: You want to achieve all with one `\author` command having some option keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I have understood the OP's request completely -- I did not change the redefinition of the `\@maketitle`.

`xkeyval` is a little bit tricky to understand in the beginning. I used the basic setup of it.

```
\define@key{authorinfo}{aff}{%
\def\VetriKVMacroAff{#1}%
}%
```

defines a key named `aff` which is intented for the affiliation number. Each time, this key is used, the macro `\VetriKVMacroAff` holds the value of, say, `aff=1`, i.e. the value is `1`. If not used, the macro `\VetriKVMacroAff` is undefined, so it's wise to check if it's defined at all.

The keys are organized in families usually, the family is called `authorinfo`.

The other keys are similarly defined.

In order to prepare `xkeyval` for the keys, `\setkeys{authorinfo}{#1}` has to be called (at best right after the `\author` 'starts')

The `\correspondence` and `\presentaddress` are global macros -- it's difficult to make a quick change to provide more failsafe replacements.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{xparse}%


\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \null
\vbox to \textheight{\vbox to \textheight{\vspace*{12pc}%\vfill%
\hbox to 10pc{\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{10pc}
{\@correspondence\par}%
    \vskip 6pt%
{\@presentaddress}%
\end{minipage}}}
\hspace*{11pc}
\vbox to \textheight{\vspace*{-44pc}%
\hbox to 10pc{\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{31pc}  
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\raggedright\fontsize{18pt}{20pt}\selectfont\@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
        \raggedright\@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
   \end{minipage}}}}%
  \par
  \vskip 8.5em}


\def\@correspondence{}
\def\correspondence#1{%
  \gdef\@correspondence{\textbf{\textit{*Correspondence:}}\newline%
    \raggedright  #1\VetriKVMacroEmail%
    }}

\def\@presentaddress{}
\def\presentaddress#1{%
     \gdef\@presentaddress{\textbf{\textit{$\dagger$presentaddress:}}\newline%
       \raggedright  #1}}



\define@key{authorinfo}{aff}{%
\def\VetriKVMacroAff{#1}%
}%


\define@key{authorinfo}{coraddress}{%
\def\VetriKVMacroCorAddress{#1}%
}%

\define@key{authorinfo}{email}{%
\def\VetriKVMacroEmail{#1}%
}%

\define@key{authorinfo}{presentaddress}{%
\def\VetriKVMacroPresentAddress{#1}%
}%


\let\OriginalAuthor\author

\RenewDocumentCommand{\author}{+O{}+m}{%
\setkeys{authorinfo}{#1}%
\ifdef{\VetriKVMacroAff}{%
  \OriginalAuthor[\VetriKVMacroAff]{#2}%
}{%
  \OriginalAuthor{#2}% 
}%
\ifdef{\VetriKVMacroCorAddress}{%
  \correspondence{\VetriKVMacroCorAddress}%
}{%
}
\ifdef{\VetriKVMacroPresentAddress}{%
  \presentaddress{\VetriKVMacroPresentAddress}%
}{%
}%
\undef\VetriKVMacroAff%
}% End of RenewDocumentCommand.


\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development}
\author[aff={1,},coraddress={Junli Liu is Professor of Plant Molecular Biology\newline},email={\href{mailto:keith.lindsey@durham.ac.uk}{keith.lindsey@durham.ac.uk}}]{Junli Liu}
\author[aff={2},presentaddress=James Rowe continued from this author address\newline e-mail: James@durham.ac.uk]{James Rowe}
\author[aff={2}]{Keith Lindsey}
\affil[1]{Integrative Cell Biology Laboratory, School of Biological and Biomedical Sciences, The Bio physical Sciences Institute, Durham University, Durham, UK}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I got the solution

Comment: I am facing two problems to achieve my required output. The author name is auto capture and print the correspondence address. At present i am manually enter the author name coraddress={author name and address}. The second thing email command is working over right macros. The value is captured last email command output. I am using different inputs like correspondence and present address email ids given in the same email id command email={mail id here}. If it is possible to give the different inputs in the same email id command. I got the solution partially Please advice.

Comment: What does auto-capture mean? This is unclear to me

Comment: If I consider "Junli Liu" author is considering the corresponding author. So i code the "coraddress={address text only i am capturing}" in the optional command. The author name "Junli Liu" string is automatically capture the "\author[]{Junli Liu}" tag and print the autor name first in the corresponding section and continued with corresponding address. Sometimes if i made changes any corrections is doing author name in author tag that will be reflected corresponding section also. email={id here} command is working over right macros. The different input values get the single email={}. Pls Advice

Comment: @Vetri: Sorry, I don't understand this procedure

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply. If i coded "coraddress={Junli Liu is Professor of Plant Molecular Biology\newline}" means this author consider as a corresponding author. Please watch the above coraddress coding. The author name "Juli Liu" is manually coded. My requirement is not manually write the author name in coraddress tag. The name will be capture automatically like "\author[coraddress={coraddress here only}]{Junli Liu name auto capture here}". If you know any idea kindly share with me.

Comment: @Vetri: Captured from where/what? I don't understand this!

Comment: Your solution is good. Your key value concept is very helpful for me to achieve the required output. I need your solution for One Question. My question is each author have a seperate link like "\author[aff={1}]{\href{http://community.org/people/u/41922}{Author Name}}". I will try to capture link using key value concept like "link={link address}" For ex: \author[aff={1},link={http://community.org/people/u/41922}]{Author Name}. But i can't achieve the required output by using the key value concept. Kindly provide your solution.